# how can i send Array of image files to php server

Tags: android

I make an application using APIs..In that i have to send array of image to php Api at a time..i don't want to use for loop to call url again and again..

**In my code i m using :**

**"file body"** method to send an image from android app to php web-service. now i want to send multiple image at a time.

so i want to send that images in array form so i can send multiple image to php web-service link at a time. how can i send array of image using file body method or any other one.

this is my code

```
file = new File(AccountDetail._StrSelectImagePath);
cbFile = new FileBody(file, "image/jpeg");
```

in that `_StrSelectImagePath` is the path of the single image...

Comment: open an http connection and send them

Comment: i think you'll run out of memory trying to open and send multiple image files in 1 swoop

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use a loop? If you created a thread to send the file, you could spawn multiple threads to send multiple files, which could all run in the background at the same time.

I think this would be much simpler, especially if you already have working code in place to send an image.

-Woody